# Meaning, in context, of the idiom 'whole cloth'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I want to ask a question which is oft-repeated question. And it might lead you to imagine that I am asking it again. Even, in this website, it has proposed before. But, as a matter of fact, I haven't understood all of its meaning yet. This idiom is **whole cloth**. There are a lot of definition for this idiom on the internet.

First, I'll link to the three definitions of *whole cloth* that appear in [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/whole_cloth):

> **1.** A newly made textile which has not yet been cut. **2.** (*figuratively, used attributively or preceded by various prepositions*) The fictitious material from which complete fabrications, lies with no basis in truth, are made. **3.** Something made completely new, with no history, and not based on anything else.

I have come across this idiom in the following two contexts in which I don't understand the meaning of the sentences completely. First, in an article by G.H. Cohen:

> The relationship between theory and political practice is more complex than some friends of the Labour Party appear now to suppose. The point of theory is not to generate a comprehensive social design which the politician then seeks to implement. Things don't work that way, because implementing a design requires **whole cloth**, and nothing in contemporary politics is made out of whole cloth. Politics is an endless struggle,and theory serves as a weapon in that struggle,because it provides a characterisation of its direction, and of its controlling purpose.

Second, in an English translation of Karl Marx's "The Eighteenth Brumaire of Louis Napoleon," chapter 1:

> Man makes his own history, but he does not make it out of the **whole cloth;** he does not make it out of conditions chosen by himself, but out of such as he finds close at hand.

Which meaning of this idiom fits in these sentences? I know the meaning of it in more simple sentences such as:

> His account of being drugged, kidnapped and tortured was made up of whole cloth. [George Carver]

But I don't know it in the above-mentioned sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Whole cloth** would refer to a bolt of fabric, as distinct from smaller pieces.

When you have a full bolt, you can make pretty much anything you like. You have enough for any pattern. But if you have less than a full bolt, or only a few scraps remaining, then your range of options is more limited. You may need to use other fabric, with a contrasting pattern, say, and thus the final product would be one that must somehow harmonize a potential conflict of color, pattern,  texture, or weight.

In politics, a "full bolt" (working with whole cloth) would be an analogy for *carte blanche*, the ability to do as one pleased, without regard for competing interests. The resulting product could have a uniformity of vision (conformity to some theoretical purity of purpose), whereas competing interests cause laws to become a "patchwork".

Comment: Thank you .your explanation is great.if you wanted to rewrite(and simplify) the first text that I brought . how would you  do it?

Comment: That's your assignment.

Comment: OK,is it correct my rewriting?things don't work that way,because implementing a design requires an unconditional authorite, and there isn't in politics the absolute power.

Comment: Yes. An implementation which conforms to a theoretical purity of design is possible only if there is no political disagreement; that happens only when  everyone agrees (which is unlikely in a democracy) or when disagreement is not permitted (as in an authoritarian system).